# Why must Voldemort's body be killed last?

Tags: harry-potter

Voldemort has horcruxes to grant him "immortality" (more like regeneration). But if his body is destroyed, why wouldn't destroying the other horcruxes afterwards not kill him just as easily? Why does the order matter?